# Making Django forms act like HTML input tags

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms

So I am making a blog using Django. I want users to be able to search by date. Before I switched over to using a forms.py file, I was using a form that included this:

```
<input type = "date">
```

When I do this, the input has a nice little button on the right side of the input box that pulls up a premade calendar. However, when my form comes out of this code in a forms.py file:

```
class Query(forms.Form):
blog_author = forms.ChoiceField(choices = AUTHOR_NAME_CHOICES, label = "Author", required = False)
blog_date = forms.DateField(label = "Publish Date", required = False)
```

It works just fine, but I lose the calendar HTML structure. How can I get that back in there?

Here's where it comes into the template on the search.html page, for reference:

```
<form action = "/home/query/" method = "get">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_table }}
<input type = "submit" value = "Find">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the OP is asking how to get

```html
<input type="date">
```

html5 built-in form function into play

You could use:

```
    custom_date = forms.CharField(label=u'Pick Date', widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'date', }))
```

The above will render you an html5 type="date" output in the form.

But be warned.

Browsers will have different or even non-existent implementations for this html5 feature.  You should not rely on it and instead use django related date picker or widgets that will guarantee you cross-browser UI.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. It's seemed to have worked in the past with Chrome and Edge, so I'm reasonably confident in it, but I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: FF does not work. In my case instead of using any JS hacks or relying on html5 form factors I use the SelectDateWidget from django.forms.extras.widgets with plain drop-downs for mm/dd/yyyy or in mm/yyyy format. It's simple and has less chance of breaking.